# LANDSAT 8 LC08 L2SP T1 data

Tags: qgis, ndvi, landsat

I want to know if Landsat 8 LC08 L2SP T1 data needs any preprocessing before using it to calculate indices such as NDVI?

Comment: L2SP products are processed to surface reflectance. In general, you just need to apply a scaling factor of 0.0000275  + -0.2 before getting things ready to compute NDVI.

Comment: @Rex Thank you so much